# WordPress on a subfolder but accessible from root

Tags: redirect, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've searched quite a lot without finding a solution.

I have a wordpress blog in `/_wp` and something else in `/other`

What I'm trying to is that every request gets redirected to the WordPress. Except those to `/other` and its child directories. I also want the access to the blog to be rewritten. Few examples to make it clear:

```
/ --> /_wp/

/ablogpost --> /_wp/ablogpost

/other --> /other

/other/bingou --> /other/bingou
```

I've tried a few things but what seems the most logical to me is:

- don't touch the .htaccess of /_wp/
- edit the .htaccess of the root '/' by adding:

  ```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mywebsite.com$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/other|/other/.*)$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /other/$1
  ```

## EDIT

So i've set correctly the /_wp dir as explained online. Though I can't access to `/other` this is my htaccess now:
    RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I was thinking of adding `RewriteRule ^other - [L]` though it still doesn't work....

Answer (score 0):

Follow instructions on [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) in Codex.

Comment: I actually did. I know have a nice wordpress working. Though my `other` folder still doesn't work I get 404 errors all the time :( (I'm editing my question with the new .htaccess